# PHP + Simple HTML DOM: Select a tag inside a div with class inside another div with class

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

In PHP: Simple HTML DOM, How do I select all `<strong>` tag that are inside `div` with class `abc`, which are inside `div` with class `123`:

```
<div class="123">
 <div class="abc">
  <strong>Text</strong>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In Javascript, sure you can, but in PHP you cannot. PHP runs at server side, which means all the communication between front and back end are made through requests. You should actually select this element using javascript and then send out to the PHP as a param of a request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a selector like `div.123 div.abc strong` and get the first element of the result. Here is a working example:

```
<?php

require 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html =<<<html
<div class="123">
 <div class="abc">
  <strong>Text</strong>
 </div>
</div>
html;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

$dom = str_get_html($html);
$el = $dom->find('div.123 div.abc strong', 0);
print $el;
print "\n";
print $el->innertext;
```

Result:

```
<strong>Text</strong>
Text
```

You can refer to the [manual](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm) for a better understanding of how selectors work.